# How to tag / organize my Twitter favorites?

Tags: twitter, twitter-favorites

I heavily use Twitter favorites for bits of information that I will likely need later. However, they are nearly useless before I have some way to organize my favorites -- with tags or something similar.

**What tools exist that can help in organizing/tagging my Twitter favorites?**

Find below a list of the researched items I was able to find thusfar:

---

Quora has a [similar thread](https://www.quora.com/What-tools-exist-to-organize-my-Twitter-favorites), but most answers there are outdated / unhelpful today:

- [Diigo](http://blog.diigo.com/2010/11/30/introduce-%E2%80%9Csave-favorite-tweets%E2%80%9D-to-save-your-favorite-tweets-to-diigo/): looks like it was down at the time of post, but is currently online. Has limit of 20 favorites per day in a free edition. Has Android app, which allows to tag items (among other things). [Its founder admitted](https://www.quora.com/What-tools-exist-to-organize-my-Twitter-favorites/answer/Joel-Liu) back in 2010 that Diigo is not convenient for this purpose (and it seems true today).
- [Pinboard.in](http://pinboard.in/): imports favorites, but unclear whether it allows to tag them. One-time $10.28 with no trial period, 3-days-moneyback guarantee--not sure it's worth the risk, with its only [few dozens thousand of active users](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinboard.in).

---

- [Faavorite.com](http://faavorite.com/): out of business
- [faveous.com](http://www.faveous.com/): doesn't allow to register
- [Laterstars](http://laterstars.com/): parked domain
- [Twitmark](http://twitmark.me/): parked domain
- [Favorious](http://favorious.com/): site not responding
- [Keepstream](http://keepstream.com/): now a part of B2B service; I found no consumer service
- [Tweetnest](http://pongsocket.com/tweetnest/): a hosted solution
- [Favstar.fm](http://favstar.fm/): not ever promised to tag favorites, but still mentioned in the thread

Comment: Speaking of IFTTT which is also the way to connect Evernote: I just wonder how Pinboard could be more reliable / long-living (and rich in extensions etc) compared to Evernote?

Answer (score 2):

[moved from a series of comments into an answer]

Using an IFTTT [recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/130648) for sending the favorites to Pinboard:

[image]

you can automatically tag tweets that you favorite with a dynamic set of parameters:

[image]

You can then go into Pinboard and batch retag a group of tweets with whatever other information you want to include.  Pinboard has a built-in subsection that saves your favorite tweets automatically anyway, if you link your Twitter account, but it does not seem to offer tagging of them.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick-n-dirty solution, I set up Twitter-to-Evernote integration by Zapier: every time I favorite a tweet, Zapier creates a new item at Evernote, with a reminder for "today + 2 days". Then I'm supposed to regularly tag new items at Evernote.

Will see how it works; questions&comments welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[Favourites.io](https://www.favourites.io/) looks a promising solution, though its free version is limited to 3K likes (and 3 searches per month, 10 collections).